# Clicking button in cypress does not have any effect

Tags: javascript, cypress

When cypress clicks the button it seems the click does not have any effect, because clicking manually on the button I see a message confirmation.
This is the HTML code from the button:

[image]

the Step definition file:

```
When("I click Save button",() =>{
    backofficeCreateDeleteClerkPage.saveBtn().click({froce:true})
})
```

and the js for the button

```
saveBtn() {
        return cy.get('im-page.hydrated').shadow().find('im-button.hydrated').contains('Save')
        
    }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is the class `btn regular success` unique to the element in question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use the button text `Save` and use contains for this:

```js
cy.get('im-page.hydrated', {includeShadowDom: true})
  .find('im-button', {includeShadowDom: true})
  .eq(2)
  .find('button', {includeShadowDom: true})
  .click({force: true})
```

In case you dont want to add `{includeShadowDom: true}` in your code or repeat it, you can just write it once in your `cypress.json` and then by default commands like `get`, `find` etc will traverse shadow DOM's.

Comment: the button still is not clicked @Alapan

Comment: Updated my answer. Can you check now

Comment: still the same, the test does not fail but the button is not clicked

Comment: Updated my answer. Please directly use the command for now into the step def file instead of using a function. Also, check with and without using `{force: true}`.

Comment: the last one worked and I used it in the function.

Answer (score 0):

Is "force" misspelled here?

`backofficeCreateDeleteClerkPage.saveBtn().click({froce:true})`

Comment: Yes, it was misspelled, funny thing is Cypress didn't catch this. Ok, I have it corrected now, but the button is not being clicked yet.

Answer (score 0):

You've got multiple shadows. You should be able to find it like this.

```
cy.find('im-button.hydrated')
  .shadow()
  .contains('Save')
```